# Number of solutions of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have a polynomial with $n$ variables and degree $r$, of the form
$$f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=c+\sum_{S\subset [n],|S|=r}c_s\prod_{i\in A}x_i$$
where $c$ is some constant and $c_s$ are coefficients that depend on the chosen subset $S\subset [n]$ (I believe this is called a multinomial but am not sure).
What is the maximal number of solutions that the equation $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=0$ can have? Is it the degree ($r$) as in the single variable case?

Comment: Already with degree 1, $f(x,y)=1-x-y$ has the whole line as solutions.  I think the intersection of $n-1$ equations might have a finite number of solutions in the general case (that is, so long as the equations don't have a common factor)

Comment: Right.... ok, and if I would say that I have $n$ equations of this form $f_j(x_i,\cdots,x_n)$, $1\leq j\leq n$ (the coefficients $c_s$ can be different between the equations) and a constraint in the sum $\sum_i x_i =a$ for some fixed $a$?

Comment: I should have said $n$ equations.  You now have $n+1$ equations because $f_{n+1}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1+\cdots+x_n-a=0$ is also an equation, and there might be no solutions.

Comment: I know of at least one solution and try to decide whether it is the only one, but I can’t seem to find a clear characterization of the number of solution a multinomial system of equation have. Can I bound the number of solutions from above? Is there a general upper bound on the number of solutions that a system of n polynomial equations of degree r and n variables can have?

Comment: I think the maximum number is the product of the degrees of the equations

Comment: But this would mean that adding more equations is adding more solution, which doesn't make sense

Comment: Sorry, I mean infinitely many solutions for fewer than $n$ equations ($n$ is the number of variables), and that product if there are $n$ or more solutions.  If you want integer solutions, that is a whole other thing, but of course there can't be more integer solutions than real ones

Comment: Great, so in this case you mean that the number of solutions will be $r^n$, right? But if I had $m$ equations ($m>n$ and $n$ is still the number of variables) I still get that adding more equations adds more solutions.... Now I will have $r^m$ solutions. What am I missing? Could you maybe help me with a pointer to a source that confirms this result? I can't seem to find one using the "standard" search lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n>1$ then $f$ can have infinitely many solutions; consider the polynomial $f(x,y)=xy$.